# Shallower bowl or longer dough hook for Kitchen Aid 7qt Stand Mixer?

Tags: equipment, mixing, stand-mixer

I have a 7qt lifter style kitchen aid stand mixer and use it often to make bread and pizza doughs.

Generally works great for very large batches, but I find that either the 7qt bowl is too deep or the dough hook isn't quite long enough and smaller batches end up with more than half of the ingredients hanging out below the hook.

Are the 6 qt bowls compatible, but shallower?   Is there a longer dough hook available?   Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to check to be sure your bowl is properly calibrated when at its lifted position. They explain how to do this on the [Kitchen Aid site](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/-%5BKSM7586PCA%5D-401694/KSM7586PCA/). If you're missing a lot of the contents, it sounds like your bowl is not lifting correctly.

Comment: @Catija Thanks.  Wasn't aware of that and gave a look.  Screw was adjusted to almost the maximum height.  Even at the maximum, the hook still clears the bottom of the bowl by quite a bit.  This is the hook that came with the (brand new) machine.

Comment: It's possible your batch is simply too small/mixer is too big. There's a reason I have three sizes of Cuisinart in my kitchen... well, that's why I have two of them... the third one is just because I haven't gotten all of the slicing blades/basic lid for the biggest one, so ... yeah.

Comment: @Catija Bummer.  I really wanted the 6/7 qt model as it has a much more powerful motor and I use the device to grind meats often.   I really don't want to consume the space with a second model.   Oh, well, maybe I'll just work on my arm muscles for smaller batches. :)

Comment: Based on my old KSM5, working your arm muscles is usually a better bet than KA dough hooks anyway. Or make twice as much and freeze half the dough for later, since you are happy with yours on large batches.

Answer (score -1):

It is most likely that your bowl is simply too big for the recipe batch size.
I habe a 5qt KA Pro Model lift bowl style.

For Easter 2018 I made half a batch of my buttorn roll recipe. That size batch called for only 1-1/4 cups of A-P flour and I quickly learned that I was going to make those for dinner, I was going to have to mix then knead the dough the old-fashioned way = by hand.

Turned out great and added a note in my cookbook to avoid the extra cleanup.